# Paypal Recurring Payments

Tags: paypal

Here is what I need:

Let's say I have a hotel rooms rental website

People can come rent a room for some period and pay with paypal(first they pay, than thay get a room)

In some cases person might want to use some services when they are staying in hotel (like room service, mini bar, etc.) - So after person leaves I need to charge them with that extras..

How it works in paypal ? the only thing I found is subscribe options - but they are like per-month, per-day subscriptions.. And I need manually charge some amount from customer from my site

Does it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way of doing that is to pre-authorize a charge for $200-$500 without completing the transaction. After person leaves you add up everything and finalize the transaction with the right amount. You can do that using PayPal API if you have Website Payments Pro ($30/month). Check "Authorization Payment Action" on page 93 in WPP Integration Guide:

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_WPP_IntegrationGuide.pdf

Comment: Does it possible to split into two transactions? For me this a requirement that first we charge user before he come to hotel and second time after he leaves

Comment: Also does not seems to be a solution for me - from pdf - "An authorization payment action represents an agreement to pay and places the buyer’s funds on hold for up to three days." - three days is kinda small period for me.. people can book room in couple month and stay there for any time they want

Comment: PayPal really didn't plan for such scenarios. You can accept PayPal payment for the room (room rate * number of days) in time of reservation, then use "Order Payment Action" when guest checks in, which will allow you to finalize during 29 days. But I think you'll be better off using real credit card processing company that allows flexibility for things like accidental charges.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you total up all amounts for all selected services and then pass that total amount to paypal.

Another option is to send a 'cart-overview' with multiple items to paypal. This way you can seperate the rental price from the extra options prices (like breakfast, full pension, etc). Some info about setting up a multiple-items cart can be found [here](http://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_howto_checkout_outside#methodtwo)

Comment: it does not work like this

There is a thousands of services that I can provide...

Let's say you want a room, you pay like $100 for couple days.. but when you stay you decided to drink some Hennessy  - that would be extra $50, than you broke a TV - that's extra $500, and so on..

Comment: IMO it could still be the same. Add another table called something like `stay_extras`, provide that table with a relation to the booking. Then each time something has been ordered or added (or broken ;)) the user (at the hotel) should add an extra row in the `stay_extras` table. When a person / couple / family leaves total up the stay_extra rows matching their booking, print it out, send it the way i described before to paypal. I don't really think there are that much other options..

Comment: No.. it just not possible.. I could not guess all possible extras like broking TV or buying some very expensive stuff, renting cars, etc. etc.

Comment: $50 rooms, Hennessy and broken TVs? What sort of hotel is this?